# Refreshing SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Background**

I have a huge table (`Table A`) in my database. From which, I apply some filters based on business rules. I then apply these filters into another table (`Table B`).

Therefore, `Table B` will always contain data from A and will always be much smaller. `Table A` contains 500,000 entries and `Table B` contains 3000 entries.

Both tables have the same structure.

**Issue**

The huge table (`Table A`) can be updated at any moment without notice. Therefore, to ensure that `Table B` contains the most up-to-date business data, it needs to be refreshed regularly. In this instance, I do this once a week.

**Solution**

How I go about this is by setting up a simple stored procedure that does the following:

1. TRUNCATE Table B
2. Apply filters on `Table A` and `INSERT` data into `Table B`

Issue with this is the fact that I have to truncate the table every week. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this, rather than deleting all the data and inserting the data into table all over again?

Is there a way to check which values are in A that are missing in B and add them accordingly?

Thanks

Comment: Just create a view, rather than having a separate table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - can this view be interrogated the same way as a table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - in addition, does the view automatically update when original table is changed?

Comment: Both of your questions: yes.

Comment: @OdaySalim, make sure you have indexes on the large table to optimize the queries via the view.

Comment: You could even go for a [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that in a stored procedure, create a View. View keep in sync with the table, as the data changes in the Table A the View will automatically update.
Here are some details you may want to read about [Views and how they work.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-2017)

[How to create Views](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-views/)